# Extracting sequences from RDD in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to prepare my data for a machine learning algorithm on Spark using pyspark. I have an RDD containing epoch date-times, IDs and classes (0 or 1). It simply looks like below:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([Row(my_date=1465488788,id=4,my_class=1), Row(my_date=1465488790,id=5,my_class=0), Row(my_date=1465488801,id=23,my_class=1), Row(my_date=1465488805,id=23,my_class=1), Row(my_date=1465488809,id=5,my_class=0), Row(my_date=1465488810,id=32,my_class=0),Row(my_date=1465488826,id=38,my_class=1)])
```

This data is ordered by date. What I want to do is extracting sequences from this data: The consecutive entries within the same time window in this RDD should go into the same sequence. For example all the data within 20 seconds time interval should be in the same sequence. If the sequence time window is 20 seconds for the above data set, I will need to create following 3 sequences:

```
[Row(my_seq=[4,5,23,23], my_class=1),Row(my_seq=[5,23,23,5,32], my_class=0),Row(my_seq=[5,32,38], my_class=1)]
```

The class numbers should be the latest element's class in the sequence. Since my data set is going to be quite big, I need to do this in parallel. I tried to do this by grouping data on the date field, but it didn't work:

```
def createSequences(in_arr):
    in_arr = list(in_arr)
    seq_arr = []
    sorted_arr = []
    for e in in_arr:
        seq_arr.append(e["id"])
        sorted_arr.append(int(str(e["my_date"]) + str(e["my_class"])))
    sorted_arr.sort()
    if str(sorted_arr[-1])[-1] == "1":
        return Row(is_class = 1, seq = seq_arr, sorted_arr = sorted_arr)
    else:
        return Row(is_class = 0, seq = seq_arr, sorted_arr = sorted_arr)
offset = 1465488788
time_window = 20
grouped = clustered_logs.map(lambda row: (int((row["my_date"] - offset) / time_window), row)) \
                        .groupByKey() \
                        .map(lambda l: createSequences(l[1]))
```

It just groups all the entries within the same window size into the same sequence and I can't use the latest entries in a sequence if they're also within the time window of the next first sequence. Can you please help me with this, if there is a way to achieve this on Spark?
Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

```
time_window = 20
clustered_logs.groupBy(lambda x: (int(x /time_window), x.my_class) )\
    .map(lambda x: Row(my_class=x[0][1], my_seq=[ t.id for t in x[1]]) )
```

- identify the window by `int(x /time_window)`
- Group by the window and class. The grouping key is a tuple `(window, class)`
- While `map`ing this `x` is a tuple like `( (73274439, 1) , itrable<Row>)`. The second value in the tuple is iterated using `for` comprehension to create a list.

Reference: [Scala doc RDD](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But by this way, I'm losing some (actually a lot of) sequences if they overlap between two time windows. For example if my data is ABBCDB and the ABBC belongs to the first time window, it groups the next sequence starting from the second DB part. But I want it to be ABBC, BBCD, BCDB and so on. I think it is not possible, is it? Thanks...